# Can i control Ubuntu 12.10 desktop while it is being remotely controlled?

Tags: login, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remote-control

Me and a friend are trying to do a certain activity on my Ubuntu desktop; it is a program on my computer that he and I want to work on remotely. So naturally the remote login feature occurred to me, but i was wondering if i could control the OS at the same time he is?

Comment: see brainstorm http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/7861/

Comment: Why would your friend need to control the OS, just to use a program remotely? Is the program the two of you want to use designed to receive input from several sources at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse,

Please check my answer here:

[Remote desktop for multiple users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247115/remote-desktop-for-multiple-users/287371#287371)

X2go and ssh Works with better support and features for linux remote desktop. (Like, file sharing, clipboard sharing, sound over net, web client, etc).

There are other ways to do it, but it worked for me, so I post it.